# Why JSON_PARSER_ERROR on such a simple object?

Tags: api, json

I am trying to create a new Opportunity in Salesforce, using their API. I am sending this object:

```
{"Amount":"5000","CloseDate":"2015-12-01","StageName":"Prospecting","Name":"Rollio Sales Cloud-TEC"}
```

to this url:

```
 https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Opportunity/
```

I get:

```
 status 400 {:orig-content-encoding nil, :trace-redirects ["https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Opportunity/"], :request-time 162, :status 400, :headers {"Connection" "close", "Transfer-Encoding" "chunked", "Content-Type" "application/json;charset=UTF-8", "Sforce-Limit-Info" "api-usage=300/15000", "Expires" "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT", "Set-Cookie" "BrowserId=l27XiqOOTZGHhCxw60pHEw;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Mon, 04-Jan-2016 04:43:12 GMT", "Date" "Thu, 05 Nov 2015 04:43:12 GMT"}, :body "[{\"message\":\"Can not deserialize SObject out of VALUE_STRING token at [line:1, column:1]\",\"errorCode\":\"JSON_PARSER_ERROR\"}]"}
```

What does this mean?

```
  Can not deserialize SObject out of VALUE_STRING token at [line:1, column:1]
```

If I go here:

```
  http://jsonlint.com/
```

and put in the above JSON, then I am told it is valid JSON. So what is the problem that Salesforce has?

How can I get a more detailed error message?

If I simplify the object to this:

```
   {"StageName":"Prospecting","Name":"Rollio Sales Cloud-TEC"}
```

I still get the same error.

I don't get "MISSING REQUIRED FIELD".

I do get "JSON_PARSER_ERROR".

Comment: I tried same json in workbench rest explorer and it worked for me. how you are passing this to SDFC side. as POST body correct ?

Comment: as an aside, if you are creating an Opportunity, usually one includes a value for `accountId` although the schema certainly allows for Oppos w/o Accounts

Comment: Crop1645, thank you for that. If the user sends us a string such as "Eventa Meva" and we have no account by that name, I am assuming that I must first create the account, then fetch the id of that account, and then use that ID for the AccountID field?

Comment: The error message makes it sound like you've quoted the entire thing when sending, post your code that actually makes the HTTP request.

Comment: Larry - "yes" is the answer to your question but note you are using the standard SFDC REST API so you'll need a trigger or process builder flow to handle the Account location/creation and subsequent update to Opportunity. An alternative would be a custom Apex rest service that does it all

Comment: superfell, you were correct! I JSON encoding it, but I was also using a library that JSON encoded it, so it was getting double encoded. Good work!

Comment: crop1645, I do not know much about Salesforce and I am not sure how I would use a trigger or process builder flow to handle the Account location/creation. Can't I just do a Create on Account, then fetch the ID, then create the Opportunity? I mean, can't I write those 3 actions in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the Amount without the quotes around the number

```
{"Amount":5000,"CloseDate":"2015-12-01","StageName":"Prospecting","Name":"Rollio Sales Cloud-TEC"}
```